# How to get same words two time in hangman using python

Tags: python

Here's my code, everything works I think except it doesn't take any value more than one. Please help me out.

```html
word = input("What's your word?\n").upper()
forguess = " ".join(word)
char = "_"
for index in range(len(word)):
    word = word[:index] + char + word[index+1:]
spacedwords = " ".join(word)
print(spacedwords)

chances = 5

while chances != 0:
    print("You have " + str(chances) + " chances left\n")
    letter = input("Guess the letters: \n").upper()
    if letter in forguess:              #check if the input letter is in original word
        pos = forguess.index(letter)    #gets the letter position from forguess original word
        spacedwords = spacedwords[:pos] + letter + spacedwords[pos+1:]  #replace word in the blank ones
        print(spacedwords)
        if spacedwords == forguess:
            print("YOU WON!!!")
            break
    else:
        chances -= 1
        if chances == 0:
            print("YOU LOOSE!!!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why your code does not work is that, while `spacedwords` changes when you guess a letter, `forguess` does not. This way your `index` call always just finds the first occurrence of `letter`. Trying to modify your code as little as possible (there would be more efficient ways to do this), here an example of how to achieve what you want:

```
word = input("What's your word?\n").upper()
forguess = " ".join(word)
char = "_"
for index in range(len(word)):
    word = word[:index] + char + word[index+1:]
spacedwords = " ".join(word)
print(spacedwords)

chances = 5

while chances != 0:
    print("You have " + str(chances) + " chances left\n")
    letter = input("Guess the letters: \n").upper()
    if letter in forguess:              #check if the input letter is in original word
        positions = [i for i,x in enumerate(forguess) if x == letter]    #gets all letter positions from forguess original word
        for pos in positions:
            spacedwords = spacedwords[:pos] + letter + spacedwords[pos+1:]  #replace all blank positions with letter
        print(spacedwords)
        if spacedwords == forguess:
            print("YOU WON!!!")
            break
    else:
        chances -= 1
        if chances == 0:
            print("YOU LOOSE!!!")
```

**EDIT**:

As the first time around I misunderstood what the OP intended to do, here again an example that tries to modify the original code as little as possible. I introduced a new variable `original` that in the beginning is identical to `forguess`. Now, every time a letter is guessed correctly, `forguess` is modified (the guessed letter is changed into a `NULL` character), so that in the next search it will not show up again. Then, in the end `spaceedwords` is compared to `original` instead of `forguess`.

```
word = input("What's your word?\n").upper()
forguess = " ".join(word)
original = " ".join(word)
char = "_"
for index in range(len(word)):
    word = word[:index] + char + word[index+1:]
spacedwords = " ".join(word)
print(spacedwords)

chances = 5

while chances != 0:
    print("You have " + str(chances) + " chances left\n")
    letter = input("Guess the letters: \n").upper()
    if letter in forguess:              #check if the input letter is in original word
        pos = forguess.index(letter)   #gets the letter position from forguess original word
        spacedwords = spacedwords[:pos] + letter + spacedwords[pos+1:]  #replace word in the blank ones
        forguess = forguess[:pos] + chr(0) + forguess[pos+1:]

        print(spacedwords)
        if spacedwords == original:
            print("YOU WON!!!")
            break
    else:
        chances -= 1
        if chances == 0:
            print("YOU LOOSE!!!")
```

**Note**:

The whole problem would be much more easy to handle, if you converted you `forguess` into a list of single characters.

Comment: Write now, your modified code is giving all the letter at the same time. Isn't there a way to get it single at a time?

Comment: Oh, ok, I misunderstood how the code should work. I'll adjust the solution accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas. I am beginner and just playing around with the code. Your help means a lot.